# file.show and user input in a loop

Tags: r, loops, plot, tiff

I have a dataframe `data` with information on tiffs, including one column `txt` describing the content of the tiff. Unfortunately, `txt` is not always correct and we need to correct them by hand. Therefore I want to loop over each row in data, show the tiff and ask for feedback, which is than put into `data$txt.cor`.

```
setwd(file.choose())
```

Some test tiffs (with nonsene inside, but to show the idea...):

```
txt <- sample(100:199, 5)

for (i in 1:length(txt)){
tiff(paste0(i, ".tif"))
plot(txt[i], ylim = c(100, 200))
dev.off()
}
```

and the dataframe:

```
pix.files <- list.files(getwd(), pattern = "*.tif", full.names = TRUE)
pix.file.info <- file.info(pix.files)
data <- cbind(txt, pix.file.info)
data$file <- row.names(pix.file.info)
data$txt.cor <- ""
data$txt[5] <- 200 # wrong one
```

My feedback function (error handling stripped):

```
read.number <- function(){
 n <- readline(prompt = "Enter the value: ")
 n <- as.character(n) #Yes, character. Sometimes we have alphanumerical data or leading zeros
 }
```

Now the loop, for which help would be very much appreciated:

```
for (i in nrow(data)){
  file.show(data[i, "file"]) # show the image file
  data[i, "txt.cor"] <- read.number() # aks for the feedback and put it back into the dataframe
}
```

In my very first attempts I was thinking of the plot.lm idea, where you go through the diagnostic plots after pressing return. I suspect that plot and tiffs are not big friends. `file.show` turned out to be easier. But now I am having a hard time with that loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't loop over the data, you only evaluate the last row. Simply write `1:nrow(data)`to iterate over all rows.

To display your tiff images in R you can use the package `rtiff`:

```
library(rtiff)
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  tif <- readTiff(data[i,"file"]) # read in the tiff data
  plot(tif) # plot the image
  data[i, "txt.cor"] <- read.number() # aks for the feedback and put it back into the dataframe
}
```